# How to move to a controller on successful authentication of a Touch ID?

Tags: ios, authentication, touch

I have written all the code related to Touch ID. I can show an alert box in successful authentication. Well, I have written alert box in dispatch_queue. My query is now I want to display a new controller on successful authentication. Please help me in this case. I have written the authentication in appdelegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of options.  The simplest is just to assign a new root view controller to your keyWindow

```
 UIViewController *authenticatedViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AuthenticatedViewController"];
 [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController=authenticatedViewController;
```

You can also post a notification to your existing view controller using `NSNotificationCenter` or invoke a method on the existing view controller (you can get a reference using the `keyWindow.rootViewController` property as above.  The method would then perform a segue.

```
 MyRootVC *rootVC=(MyRootVC *([UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
 [rootVC authenticated];
```

Personally, I would move the authentication out of the AppDelegate and into the root view controller. Then it is simply a matter of executing a segue (storyboard) when authentication succeeds.

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"AuthenticatedSegue"];
```

Comment: Could you please give me an example?

Comment: Are you using storyboards or nib files?

Comment: I'm using storyboards.

Comment: Thanks Paul used performsegue.